# Set Java Enviromental Variables

Tags: java, jvm, environment-variables, netbeans-8

I am having problems to set up properly the Java Environmental Variables.

I have a Windows 7 - 64 bit PC, and when I rUn my Java App I get the following system info:

```
  Operating System        = Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_45; Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 24.45-b08; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_45-b18
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
```

but the JAVA_HOME environmental variable is set to the 64 bit JVM "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"

I thought the App would take the JVM from JAVA_HOME but it seems it is not the case.

How should the App or the Environmental variable be set to run the 64 bit JVM?

Comment: How are you running your java app?

Comment: Its an installed application created with the netbeans platform, the issue was solved by adding "jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45" in the .conf file of the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not used by Java itself. Some third-party software, for example Apache Tomcat, uses this to find the Java installation directory, but the JDK and JRE themselves do not look at this environment variable, so if you run your own application, that variable is not automatically used to determine which Java version to use.

If you want to run your application with whatever `JAVA_HOME` refers to, then explicitly specify it. You could for example make a batch file with the following content:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar myapplication.jar
```

Save this as `myapplication.bat` and use that to start your application.

Answer (score 1):

The application doesn't choose which JRE to use. The operating system decides that, or you decide that by executing `java` or `javaw` from a given version of the JRE. If you're double-clicking a .jar file in Windows, Windows will use whatever executable is configured to open the .jar extension. `JAVA_HOME` may be used by batch scripts to run an application with a give JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments:

In this case it was a netbeans App, and the way to set the java was in the .conf file by adding

"jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"